# Jasper Report Cannot Generate PDF

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, jasper-reports

This is my first time to use Jasper Report,
i need to generate PDF using Java Server Face JSF, so, after the PDF Generated it should downloaded by Browser

i use the netbeans code generated Web Application, with java server faces framework and primefaces

```
public void createPDF() throws IOException {
    List<Pelanggan> asdf = pelangganFacade.findAll();

    try {
        ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getContext();

        String ReportTemplate = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Blank_A4.jasper");

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("nama", asdf.get(1));

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getContext();  
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testing.pdf");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ReportTemplate, parameters);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

but it not worked and give me an error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade cannot be      cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade     cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
at com.joandilee.TestReport.createPDF(TestReport.java:55)
```

is there any simple way to do generate PDF Report using Jasper Report and then download it to browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Jasper error

replace

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext
             .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
```

to

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
```